# "Required request body is missing" error in integration tests when body is present

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, testing

I'm writing a Spring Boot application that hits two third-party APIs and returns a CSV file based on the results. My application takes a `@RequestBody` parameter which is a `List<String>` which is used in the third party calls.

I'm trying to integration test this application using a `TestRestTemplate`, and I'm getting a `HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing` error, when I'm definitely passing a body into the `HttpEntity` that is my request object.

Passing in an identical body into postman, or into a controller test using MockMvc, works just fine, but I want to automatically test the whole application end-to-end.

If there is something wrong with what I'm passing down, I'd expect it to be giving me a JSON parsing error, not a missing body error. I've tried changing the type of what I'm passing down, and setting content-type to be text/plain - neither of these have caused the error to change or disappear.

My test code:

```
package uk.co.heywood.sonarconverter.integration;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.header;
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.method;
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo;
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.response.MockRestResponseCreators.withStatus;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.web.client.ExpectedCount;
import org.springframework.test.web.client.MockRestServiceServer;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import uk.co.heywood.sonarconverter.Application;
import uk.co.heywood.sonarconverter.utils.TestUtils;

@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"sonar.qubeToken=aFakeQubeToken", "sonar.cloudToken=aFakeCloudToken"})
class SonarConverterIntegrationTest
{
    
    private static final String URL = "/api/sonar/diff";
    private static final String SONARQUBE_URL = "https://sonarqube.services.mywork.co.uk/api/issues/search?projects=myproject&componentKeys=myComponentKeys&statuses=OPEN&ps=500&p=1";
    private static final String SONARCLOUD_URL = "https://sonarcloud.io/api/issues/search?projects=myCloudProject&statuses=OPEN&ps=500&p=1";
    
    private static final String SONARQUBE_RESPONSE = TestUtils.fromFile( "integration/sonarqube-response.json" );
    private static final String SONARCLOUD_RESPONSE = TestUtils.fromFile( "integration/sonarcloud-response.json" );
    private static final String EXPECTED_RESULT = TestUtils.fromFile( "integration/result.csv" );
    
    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;
    
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private MockRestServiceServer mockRestServiceServer;
    
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        mockRestServiceServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer( restTemplate );
    }
    
    @Test
    void canCreateCsv() {
        
        mockRestServiceServer.expect( ExpectedCount.once(),
                        requestTo(SONARQUBE_URL))
                .andExpect( method(HttpMethod.GET) )
                .andExpect( header( HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer aFakeQubeToken" ) )
                .andRespond( withStatus( HttpStatus.OK )
                        .contentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
                        .body( SONARQUBE_RESPONSE ));
        mockRestServiceServer.expect( ExpectedCount.once(),
                        requestTo(SONARCLOUD_URL))
                .andExpect( method(HttpMethod.GET) )
                .andExpect( header( HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer aFakeCloudToken" ) )
                .andRespond( withStatus( HttpStatus.OK )
                        .contentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
                        .body( SONARCLOUD_RESPONSE ));
        
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add( HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE );
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>( """
                [
                    "aParameter", "anotherParameter"
                ]""", headers );
        ResponseEntity<String> response = testRestTemplate.exchange(
                URL,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                request,
                String.class
        );
        assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo( HttpStatus.OK );
        assertThat(response.getBody()).isEqualTo( EXPECTED_RESULT );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of the method `requestTo` or where you pass the request body. A complete [example] would help us to help you.

Comment: @hc_dev I've updated my code to show the full class - but it's all spring stuff, ```requestTo``` is a static method in ```MockRestRequestMatchers```, and my request body is the string being passed into ```HttpEntity```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, it's not a good idea to use `@RequestBody` with `GET` call. A better API design should make the API `POST` instead of `GET`.

With RestTemplate I am quite sure it does not support `GET` with `RequestBody` out of the box. For such scenarios you may be able to achieve it but by doing [this painful method](https://thegeekyasian.com/http-get-request-with-a-request-body-using-resttemplate/).